# How to listen playback/audio state change in UWP app

Tags: audio, uwp, media

I am developing on a UWP app which need to listen playback/audio state change. such as: can know when other app start/stop to play a audio.

On Windows, I see there is an API *"Windows.Media.Audio.AudioStateMonitor"*, but it only listen sound level change of app's own audio play.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiostatemonitor?view=winrt-22621

On Android, there is an API that fully meet my requirement. *AudioManager#registerAudioPlaybackCallback()*

**I want to query, is there any API on Windows that can listen playback/audio state change of whole Windows system. Like Android's AudioManager#registerAudioPlaybackCallback()**

Answer (score 0):

UWP runs in a sandbox and has no permission to access other app. UWP does not have related API support for this.

It is possible to use the [Windows Core Audio API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudiometerinformation-getpeakvalue)
`IAudioMeterInformation::GetPeakValue` to query whether the sound is playing.

Since UWP cannot directly use Win32 API, you need to write a project that uses Win32 API first, then package this project with the UWP project and realize the communication between the two project.

You can use `IAudioMeterInformation` [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422255/determine-if-windows-is-currently-playing-sound) in WPF, then use **Windows Application Packaging Project** to package WPF and UWP project. You can refer to this blog: [UWP with Desktop Extension](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/).

Comment: Thank Junjie.
Actually, I don't want to access other app.  But I want to receive the state change when system is start to play audio, so I can stop my music play.
Only query whether sound is playing is not enough, you know it is not possible to infinitely loop query the system sound play. I need to get the audio state change notification.

Comment: UWP doesn't have such audio state change notification. `IAudioMeterInformation` can achieve similar function, so you need to use Win32 API to query whether the sound is playing.

Comment: Thanks from your comments. Is there any Win32 APIs, support to query current playing sound type? Such as: music, communication call (such as: teams call) ...

Comment: According to my search, win32 seems to have no related APIs.