# Detect if system is playing any sound in VB .Net (and run code accordingly)

Tags: vb.net

I have a working application in VB .Net 2015 that I need to add a new feature to so that it can run a specific chunk of code IF there is any audio being played OR not. Or if the sound level (VU Meter) is above a certain limit. I searched the internet rigorously and found some code for C# and C++ but haven't been able to implement them in VB .Net. Any help is highly appreciated.

**This is the code I found that presumebly does the job in C#:**

```
public static bool IsWindowsPlayingSound()
{
    var enumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
    var speakers = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
    var meter = (IAudioMeterInformation)speakers.Activate(typeof(IAudioMeterInformation).GUID, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    var value = meter.GetPeakValue();

    // this is a bit tricky. 0 is the official "no sound" value
    // but for example, if you open a video and plays/stops with it (w/o killing the app/window/stream),
    // the value will not be zero, but something really small (around 1E-09)
    // so, depending on your context, it is up to you to decide
    // if you want to test for 0 or for a small value
    return value > 1E-08;
}

[ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
private class MMDeviceEnumerator
{
}

private enum EDataFlow
{
    eRender,
    eCapture,
    eAll,
}

private enum ERole
{
    eConsole,
    eMultimedia,
    eCommunications,
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6")]
private interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
{
    void NotNeeded();
    IMMDevice GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role);
    // the rest is not defined/needed
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F")]
private interface IMMDevice
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
    object Activate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams);
    // the rest is not defined/needed
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("C02216F6-8C67-4B5B-9D00-D008E73E0064")]
private interface IAudioMeterInformation
{
    float GetPeakValue();
    // the rest is not defined/needed
}
```

**This is my code for VB .Net (tried to immitate the above code)**
But for this line, when I try to run the sub IsWindowsPlayingSound():

```
 DirectCast(speakers.Activate(GetType(IAudioMeterInformation).GUID, 0, IntPtr.Zero), IAudioMeterInformation)
```

I get the error

**An invalid VARIANT was detected during a conversion from an unmanaged VARIANT to a managed object. Passing invalid VARIANTs to the CLR can cause unexpected exceptions, corruption or data loss.**

VB .Net Code:

```
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
    
    Namespace Foo
    
        Public Class Bar
    
            <ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")>
            Private Class MMDeviceEnumerator
            End Class
            Public Shared Function IsWindowsPlayingSound() As Boolean
    
                Dim enumerator As IMMDeviceEnumerator = DirectCast(New MMDeviceEnumerator(), IMMDeviceEnumerator)
                Dim speakers As IMMDevice = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia)
                Dim meter As IAudioMeterInformation = DirectCast(speakers.Activate(GetType(IAudioMeterInformation).GUID, 0, IntPtr.Zero), IAudioMeterInformation)
                Dim value As Single = meter.GetPeakValue()
    
                Return value > 0.00000001
            End Function
    
    
    
            Private Enum EDataFlow
                eRender
                eCapture
                eAll
            End Enum
    
            Private Enum ERole
                eConsole
                eMultimedia
                eCommunications
            End Enum
    
            <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6")>
            Private Interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
                Sub NotNeeded()
                Function GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow As EDataFlow, role As ERole) As IMMDevice
            End Interface
    
            <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F")>
            Private Interface IMMDevice
                ' <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)>
                Function Activate(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> iid As Guid, dwClsCtx As Integer, pActivationParams As IntPtr) As Object
            End Interface
    
            <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("C02216F6-8C67-4B5B-9D00-D008E73E0064")>
            Private Interface IAudioMeterInformation
                Function GetPeakValue() As String
            End Interface
        End Class
    End Namespace
    
    
    
    
    Public Class Form1
    
    
    
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Foo.Bar.IsWindowsPlayingSound()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: This is the topic I refered to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422255/determine-if-windows-is-currently-playing-sound

Comment: "haven't been able" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: Are you asking to convert that to VB.Net?  There are conversion tools that will do that.

Comment: _but haven't been able to implement them in VB .Net_: What does this mean? Why haven't you _been able to implement them_? You don't know how to program in VB.NET? You don't know how to convert from C# to VB.NET? You don't know how to program? Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for you replies people. I added my own VB code and the error I get. I'm not sure if this is even possible with VB .Net so I'm asking from veteran VB gurus to tell me what I'm doing wrong and what other viable approaches are there. Thanks

Comment: [Return: MarshalAs()] in VB.NET is set directly to the return value of the Function, and you cannot omit it. Change in `Function Activate(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> iid As Guid, dwClsCtx As Integer, pActivationParams As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> Object` -- Note that you have set the return value of `GetPeakValue() As String`, while it's `Single`

Comment: I did it (dectect if system is playing sound - device actually) in vb.net using the naudio component, see here for open source: https://github.com/roblatour/setvol/tree/main

Comment: Thanks everybody especially @Jimi for your help. Jimi, you got mad skills man. I envy you truly. I had given up completely. This is a gamechanger for my app. Keep up the great work man.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the fully funcional and errorless code thanks to Jimi's gracious comment and guidance.**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace Foo

    Public Class Bar

        <ComImport, Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")>
        Private Class MMDeviceEnumerator
        End Class
        Public Shared Function IsWindowsPlayingSound() As Boolean

            Dim enumerator As IMMDeviceEnumerator = DirectCast(New MMDeviceEnumerator(), IMMDeviceEnumerator)
            Dim speakers As IMMDevice = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia)
            Dim meter As IAudioMeterInformation = DirectCast(speakers.Activate(GetType(IAudioMeterInformation).GUID, 0, IntPtr.Zero), IAudioMeterInformation)
            Dim value As Single = meter.GetPeakValue()

            Return value > 0.00000001
        End Function



        Private Enum EDataFlow
            eRender
            eCapture
            eAll
        End Enum

        Private Enum ERole
            eConsole
            eMultimedia
            eCommunications
        End Enum

        <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6")>
        Private Interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
            Sub NotNeeded()
            Function GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow As EDataFlow, role As ERole) As IMMDevice
        End Interface

        <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F")>
        Private Interface IMMDevice
            ' <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)>
            Function Activate(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> iid As Guid, dwClsCtx As Integer, pActivationParams As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)> Object
        End Interface

        <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("C02216F6-8C67-4B5B-9D00-D008E73E0064")>
        Private Interface IAudioMeterInformation
            Function GetPeakValue() As Single
        End Interface
    End Class
End Namespace




Public Class Form1



    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim name = Foo.Bar.IsWindowsPlayingSound()
        MsgBox(name)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Check the `AudioDevice` class [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52013031/7444103), you may find it useful